# How to create a list containing numbers from 1 to given number in NetLogo?

Tags: list, netlogo

Does anyone know how to create a list containing numbers from 1 to given number in NetLogo?
It looks like [1 2 ... given number]
thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NetLogo has primitive for that called `n-values`. Very simply:

```
n-values 10 [ ? + 1 ]
```

will give you the list:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```

But there is plenty of other neat stuff you can do with `n-values`. You should take a look at [the documentation](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#n-values).

#### Update:

NetLogo 6.0 now has the [`range`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#range) primitive which can be used for the same purpose:

```
observer> print (range 1 11)
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```